# Importing excel to access with wildcards

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to import an excel document to a table that doesn't yet exist in access

I am using the following code:

```
' Import Hourly stats
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=10, _
        tablename:="Hourly", FileName:="C:\Filename\folder\stats* _
        Hasfieldnames:=True, Range:="AgentActivity!"
```

I have put the wildcard * at the end of the filename because the end half of the filename changes ever hour or so.

When I run the code I get this error:

> The Microsoft access database engine could not find the object. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing the closing quote at the end of the filename.

```
' Import Hourly stats
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=10, _
    tablename:="Hourly", FileName:="C:\Filename\folder\stats*", _
    Hasfieldnames:=True, Range:="AgentActivity!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have added the closing quote but its throwing out a run time error 3011

Comment: In that case it's probably just an issue with using wildcards for TransferSpreadsheet - I don't think you can use them in the way you are trying to for this function. You may need to set a variable in your code which finds the specific file name at that point of time - the difficulty of this depends on how it is named (is it just a datestamp?). Then you attach it to the filename part of the function as `FileName:="C:\Filename\folder\stats" & variableName,`.

Comment: @finjo Was going to make same suggestion.  However in variableName, would you use the DIR function to retrun the file name?  `variableName = dir("C:\Filename\folder\stats*")`